# Using EXTRACT() in an IIF or CASE statement in Firebird SQL

Tags: case, extract, firebird

Why wouldn't the following statement work in a firebird SQL:

```
IIF((EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED)) = 0, 
    "SUNDAY", 
    TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED)
```

The purpose if to put the date in to a "week ending" category. So no matter what date was entered in date worked, it would be shown on the report as being in week ended.

I can use a nested if or a case statement, but as the case statement didn't work, then I tried to break it down to an IFF statement. But neither liked me using the EXTRACT function which I got working by itself, but not when used in an IFF or CASE statement.

Comment: `the case statement didn't work` ... what error did the `CASE` expression give you?

Comment: Please add some sample data, the expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: I almost got the information I wanted with:
TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED+7-EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED) AS "WEEK ENDING"

If an employee worked on a 5/Jan, I want to have another column that is called Week Ending and would produce 8/1 (Sunday).
At the moment the SQL fails to run as opposed to producing an incorrect result. The above statement works except for when someone worked on a Sunday in which it adds another week. I can resolve that by using an IIf statment, but I can't get an IIF statement and EXTRACT statement to work together.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel solved the current issue, but why wouldn't the following case statement work?

CASE EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED)
    When '1' then TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED + 6 
    When '2' then TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED + 5
    When '3' then TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED + 4
    When '4' then TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED + 3
    When '5' then TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED + 2
    When '6' then TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED + 1
    else TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED
end

Is my syntax slightly wrong?

Comment: Well, the result of extract is an integer, not a string, so don't use strings in the case. And as you don't describe what you want, nor what the actual result is, it is hard to give an actual answer. I suggest that you create a new question and describe what you want and what you get.

Answer (score 1):

[IIF(Cond, Result1, Result2) is a shortcut for “CASE WHEN Cond THEN Result1 ELSE Result2 END”. You can also compare IIF to the ternary “? :” operator in C-like languages.](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-iif)

Example :

```
select iif( sex = 'M', 'Sir', 'Madam' ) from Customers
```

Use **'SUNDAY'** instead of "SUNDAY". Double quotes mean name of a field or a table for dialect 3 (Thanks Mark Rotteveel).

See [SQL Dialects](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref25-background.html#fblangref25-structure-dialects)

So, try:

```
select IIF((EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED))=0,'SUNDAY',
TIMESHEETLINES.DATEWORKED) from TIMESHEETLINES
```

Comment: Unless of course the OP is using a dialect 1 database.

Comment: There is one too many closed brackets after DATEWORKED)), but even when I fix that is has the same problem in that it won't even run. It comes up with the error:
[ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]Dynamic SQL error

Comment: That worked! I can change it slightly to get the result I want.
The only different is the ' & ', I thought I tried that, but I guess not.
Thank you.